# How can i determine that a Keystore is updated in Spring Cloud Stream API

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I create a materialized view from a topic with the aggregate function from the spring cloud stream api.
This looks like the following:

```
public void process(KStream<Object, Object> input){
input
  .peek((key, value) ->{...}
  .map((key, value) -> {...}
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5000))
  .aggregate(Initializer, Aggregator, Materialized)
```

Then i query my created Statestore with:

```
 ReadOnlyWindowStore<Object, Object> windowStore =
  queryService.getQueryableStoreType("test", QueryableStoreTypes.windowStore());
```

Now my question is how can i determine that this statestore has updated after a new event was handled by the process method? Is their somekind of event i can listen to or can i create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is:

```java
input
  .peek((key, value) ->{...}
  .map((key, value) -> {...}
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5000))
  .aggregate(Initializer, Aggregator, Materialized)
```

In fact, the last `aggregate()` returns a `KTable` object. If you disable caching via `Materialized` you can get informed about every single update to the `KTable` via:

```java
input
  .peek((key, value) ->{...}
  .map((key, value) -> {...}
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5000))
  .aggregate(Initializer, Aggregator, Materialized) // disable caching via Materialized
  .toStream()
  .foreach(...) // react to every update to the KTable
```

Comment: Is it possible to do both at once? Or should i create 2 different aggregates , one for caching and one for listening and then triggering something?

Comment: "Caching" is an overloaded term here... If you update the code as suggested, you still get your materialized view and you can still query it. "Caching" means something different and is related to downstream push updates into `foreach()` (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html)